# javascript form validation always returns true when I include one line of code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

i have spent almost 2 hours traying to solve this. I am writing a js function that shows an error message when a field is left blank. The problem is that the function always returns ***true*** when I include the line that shows the error message. here is the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
    {
        if(document.forms['login']['user'] == "")
        {
           document.forms['login']['error'].innerHTML = 'You should provide an user name';
           return false;
        }
        else
            {
              return true;
            }
    }
</script>
```

here is the form code

```
 <form id="login" name="login" role="form" method="post" action="pop.php" onsubmit="return check();">

 <p id="error" name="error" class="alarm_text"></p>
 <input class="" placeholder="User Name" id="user" name="user" value="" autofocus>

 <button type="submit" id="send" name="send" class="">Login</button>

    </form>
```

I have ommited other input files and CSS classes in the form. I have tried severals ways to show the error messaje like using CSS to display the `<p>` tag when the error hapends, does not work either. If i remove the line

```
document.forms['login']['error'].innerHTML = 'You should provide an user name';
```

the function returns false, like it should. If I change the line for something like

```
alert("You should provide an user name");
```

It also works. The problem is when I try to do something with the `<P>` tag. I also have tried using `<label>`

Comment: in input tag use **required** for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit event handler function is not finishing. It is reaching an error, which is exiting the method without returning anything, but since it isn't returning false the form is being submitted.

The child array of form is an array of inputs accessible by name. You can't access the `<p>` by name, it is not in the form input array, so your js is trying to set the innerHTML of a null object and creating a runtime error. If you run this line of code outside of your check function you'll see the error.

```
document.forms['login']['error'].innerHTML = 'You should provide an user name';
```

If you try this instead, your program will run as expected.

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'You should provide an user name';
```